# Does coverting a JAR file to an executable secure it for distribution?

Tags: java, security, jar, decompiling

I've made an application in Java, and I've converted the application jar file to an `.exe` using software to prevent extraction, since we know that JAR files can be easily extracted and de-compiled.

Can anyone please tell me whether converting the .jar file to `.exe` is safe enough for distributing to any clients.

Comment: I was wondering which software did you use to convert the jar to an exe. Also the security level will depends on that "converter", If it generated a fully .exe without depending on the JVM then it might have a better security.

Comment: You might be better off using an obfuscator like [Proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: My experience suggests that people who ask this question are not yet at a level where anyone wold *bother* stealing their codes.  And unless it used some 'non obvious algorithm' it is perfectly possible and legal to sit a bunch of people down in front of it to document the inputs & outputs.  Send that spec. to a programming team and you will usually end up with a better product, entirely legally.

Comment: I'm using exe4j software for converting jar to exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are two kinds of EXE generators:

1. Ones that attack a minimal JRE to your JAR file
2. Ones that convert your code to native code

well both are harder to decompile that pure JAR file, but 2nd ones are more secure.

Well as far as I know native compilers are all commercial, so if you need a free converter, you just have 1st option. In that case I recommend you to use a (non flow) obfuscator (such as yGuard) first, and then convert the obfuscated JAR file to EXE.

Comment: can you please suggest some free software that can do obfuscation

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is 100% safe. Converting jar to exe you are killing the super important java feature: cross-platform. Exe file is not cross platform any more. It is created for specific platform (e.g. MS windows).

If you want to prevent your code from reverse engineering use obfuscation: the process that changes your byte code so that it probably can be decompiled but it is extremely hard to understand it after de-compilation. If you want more security you can download parts of your code at runtime and run them. The downloading can be done using SSL, so it will be very secure. You can also create your custom class loader and run against password protected zip file.

So, there are a lot of ways to protect your code and creating exe file is the weakest one.

Comment: can you please tell me solution or ways i should do before distributing my application

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone please tell me whether converting the .jar file to .exe is safe enough for distributing to any clients?

No, it isn't.  Obfuscation can make it a little harder.